# Word Compression

Tags: wordplay

Compress all of these words into one!

> boxes house truck gone brisk rapid speedy fast push thread needle clear refreshing liquid delight

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "compress"? As in, are we looking for a word that connects them all, or a word that can be appended/prepended to all the words to make another? – **or is that part of the puzzle?**

Comment: @BrendonShaw I suppose I can strip all the spaces but that's hardly what you wanted to ask. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Combine the meanings of all the words to make one word. This can take multiple steps.

Comment: to me it seems like someone is taken by ambulance to hospital, fixed up and the result is delight. Like a small story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off [Luke's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/71998/17297), which you should upvote as well.

Taking the first group of words,

> boxes + house + truck + gone implies *move* or *moving*.

The second group,

> brisk, rapid, speedy, and fast are all synonyms for *quick*.

The third group,

> push + thread + needle gives *through*, as in push thread through the eye of the needle, or push thread through material with a needle.

The final group,

> clear refreshing liquid delight likely refers to *water*.

That gives us

> *move quick through water*, which combine to become *swim*

Comment: Great job! I'll post more questions like this in the future, so be on the lookout for those.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer

> boxes house truck gone -> **move**

Then

> brisk rapid speedy fast -> **run**

Then

> push thread needle -> **sew**

Then

> clear refreshing liquid delight -> **water**

Extra Thoughts

> It's possible that **move** feeds into the **run** group. Then maybe **run** feeds into the **sew** group. Not sure how **sew** and **water** relate though...

Comment: This is very good! Be careful about how you interpret the words, though.

Comment: @Luke How about rot13(frjre? frjntr?)

Answer (score 0):

first guess

I guess we could

> put together **brisk rapid speedy fast** and replace by **quick**, maybe 
>  also **thread needle** into **sew** , maybe **push** is part of this, but I don't know the specific verb for this
>  **clear refreshing liquid delight** into **soda** or **Sprite** 
>  then maybe, with the words we "compressed" we could compress even more to end up to one word only

Comment: You're on the right track!